# Warning message is displayed when starting node js server : DeprecationWarning: A boolean value was passed to options

Tags: node.js

```
(node:6340) [SEQUELIZE0004] DeprecationWarning: A boolean value was passed to options.operatorsAliases. This is a no-op with v5 and should be removed.
```

I want to solve the error

What can I do to prevent this warning message ?

git hub is this
https://github.com/hyunsokstar/node_bird_55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code as config.js :

```js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
module.exports = { 
  development: {
    "username": "root",
 "password": "nodejsbook",
 "database": "react-nodebird",
 "host": "127.0.0.1",
 "dialect": "mysql",
    operatorsAliases: Sequelize.Op,
  },  
  test: {
   "username": "root",
 "password": "nodejsbook",
 "database": "react-nodebird",
 "host": "127.0.0.1",
 "dialect": "mysql",
    operatorsAliases: Sequelize.Op,
  },  
  production: {
   "username": "root",
 "password": "nodejsbook",
 "database": "react-nodebird",
 "host": "127.0.0.1",
 "dialect": "mysql",
    operatorsAliases: Sequelize.Op,
  }
}
```

Comes from here : https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8417